# Getting value after clicking twice

Tags: angular, asynchronous, undefined, angular-promise

I have a lack of understanding asynchronous operation while I'm dealing with a promise function in angular. So basically, I'm trying to get a value from a promise method and assign it to a global variable in a component. However, the value appears to be `undefined` in the console when I click a button once, and it starts to show the value after clicking it once more.

Html:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="loadInfo(form)">Submit</button>
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class Web3Service {
    constructor...

    getInfo(address: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.TestBetting.deployed().then((instance) => {
          return instance.getInfo.call(address);
        })
        .then((value) => {
          var serialized = this.itemsService.getSerialized<IGetInfo>(value); 
          return this.mappingService.mapValueToGetInfo(serialized); 
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }  
}
```

Component:

```
export class HomeComponent {
    infoMapped: any;

    constructor(private web3Service: Web3Service) {}

    loadInfo(): void {
        var test = this.web3Service.getInfo(this.address); 
        test.then((value) => {
            this.infoMapped = value;
        })
        console.log(this.infoMapped)
    }
}
```

What needs to be fixed so that `infoMapped` value can be shown in the console after clicking the button only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
loadInfo(): void {
    var test = this.web3Service.getInfo(this.address); 
    test.then((value) => {
        this.infoMapped = value;
    })
    console.log(this.infoMapped)
}
```

> What needs to be fixed so that infoMapped value can be shown in the console after clicking the button only once?

To get that, move the `console.log(this.infoMapped)` into the promise:

```
loadInfo(): void {
    var test = this.web3Service.getInfo(this.address); 
    test.then((value) => {
        this.infoMapped = value;
        console.log(this.infoMapped)
    });
}
```

### Reasoning

This will fix because the function at `test.then(<THIS FUNCTION HERE>)` is not executed right away, but only when the `Promise` object that `test` holds (that was returned by `getInfo()`) resolves.

And it will take a bit of time for it to resolve. Millisseconds, maybe, but still won't execute right away.

It won't execute, but the code still goes on. When it goes on, it executes the  `console.log(this.infoMapped)` right away.

Now, because the `test.then(<THIS FUNCTION HERE>)` hadn't executed yet (remember: it doesn't execute right away, but some time in the near future), its code (the assignment `this.infoMapped = value;`) has not yet been executed when the `console.log(this.infoMapped)` runs.

That's why you log `undefined` the first time.

Now, by the second time you click, the first `test.then(<THIS FUNCTION HERE>)` **of the first click** has had enough time to execute. And now the `console.log(this.infoMapped)` will print the value that was updated when it ran.

(Also notice the `test.then(<THIS FUNCTION HERE>)` will execute again in the future, due to the second click, yet assigning another value - maybe identical - to `this.infoMapped`).

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, but I know that's the way to get the value right away after clicking once. My intention was to get one of the values from `this.infoMapped` and use it in the for loop right after. I will mark this as an answer, but I think I will post another question to get what I really want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970067/why-getting-the-value-after-clicking-it-twice-promise