# Why getting the value after clicking it twice? + Promise

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-promise

I have a lack of understanding asynchronous operation while I'm dealing with a promise function in angular. So basically, I'm trying to get a value from a promise method and assign it to a global variable in a component. However, I am unable to retrieve the value when I click on a button once and it finally starts to show the value after I clicked on a button once more.

Error I get when I clicked it **once**:

`Cannot read property 'matchId' of undefined`

Value I get after I clicked it **twice**:

`3`

Html:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="loadInfo(form)">Submit</button>
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class Web3Service {
    constructor...

    getInfo(address: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.TestBetting.deployed().then((instance) => {
          return instance.getInfo.call(address);
        })
        .then((value) => {
          var serialized = this.itemsService.getSerialized<IGetInfo>(value); 
          return this.mappingService.mapValueToGetInfo(serialized); 
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }  
}
```

Component:

```
export class HomeComponent {
    infoMapped: any;

    constructor(private web3Service: Web3Service) {}

    loadInfo(): void {
        var test = this.web3Service.getInfo(this.address); 
        test.then((value) => {
            this.infoMapped = value;
        })

        // this.infoMapped.matchId is undefined on a first attempt
        var length = this.infoMapped.matchId;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        //...
        }
    }
}
```

What needs to be fixed so that `infoMapped` value can be retrieved after clicking a button only once?

Comment: The problem is the same, you have to put that `var length...` and `for` inside the `.then((value) => { ... })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is still that **code after** the `test.then()` (i.e. the `for`) will execute **before** the `this.infoMapped = value;` because `this.infoMapped = value;` will only execute when the `test` promise resolves, and it will only resolve some time *after* the `for` runs.

What I suggest: move the "handling" logic to a new method and call it from the `.then()`.

So, this:

```js
loadInfo(): void {
    var test = this.web3Service.getInfo(this.address); 
    test.then((value) => {
        this.infoMapped = value;
    })

    // this.infoMapped.matchId is undefined on a first attempt
    var length = this.infoMapped.matchId;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    //...
    }
}
```

Would become this:

```js
loadInfo(): void {
    var test = this.web3Service.getInfo(this.address); 
    test.then((value) => {                 // <=== changed this line
        this.handleInfo(value)             // <=== changed this line
     });
}

handleInfo(value): void {                   // <=== added this whole method.
    this.infoMapped = value;

    var length = this.infoMapped.matchId;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Get an error doing `test.then(this.handleInfo);`, still need to pass it as `test.then((value) => {
            this.handleInfo(value);
        })`