# Need to click twice to get a response from a JavaScript promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I also have a lack of understanding with asynchronous operation while I'm dealing with promise functions like this person:

[Link to same type of question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970067/why-getting-the-value-after-clicking-it-twice-promise)

I have to click twice on a button to get the results I want and it happens each time I reload the page.

I was assigned to an exercice with 2 tasks in which I have to retrieve data from a json file and display it on the browser when a button is clicked. 1st task: using fetch API, second task; using async/await on top of the fetch API.

I think I followed what is said in the link I posted, which seems to be passing a callback function to a `.then()`.

Concerning the async await part, I don't get it. My understanding is that when I write await in front of a function, I won't receive the result until it returns. There are things that I'm missing.

Here's my code and thanks for the help.

[Link to my replit.com repo since I can't integrate my json file into the snippet](https://replit.com/join/qqwezsqxbu-groovyhooked)

```js
const asyncAwaitButton = document.querySelector("#async-await-button");
const promiseButton = document.querySelector("#promise-button");
const results1 = document.querySelector(".results1");
const results2 = document.querySelector(".results2");
const openClose1 = document.querySelector(".first");
const openClose2 = document.querySelector(".second");

let arr = [];
let artistsData = [];

const stickerMaker = (element, result) => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "artist";
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  img.src = element.image;
  h1.innerText = element.name;
  div.append(img, h1);
  result.appendChild(div);
};

const removeChilds = (parent) => {
  while (parent.lastChild) {
    parent.removeChild(parent.lastChild);
  }
};

const storeInArray = (value) => {
  value.forEach((element) => {
    arr.push({ name: element.name, image: element.image });
  });
};

const fetchArtist = () => {
  fetch("./api/artists.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => storeInArray(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  
  if (results1.hasChildNodes()) {
    openClose1.innerHTML = "Closed";
    removeChilds(results1);
  } else {
    openClose1.innerHTML = "Open";
    arr.forEach((element) => stickerMaker(element, results1));
  }
}

const asyncAwaitCall = async () => {
  const results = await fetch("./api/artists.json");
  results.json().then((e) => artistsData.push(e));
  return await artistsData[0].forEach((element) => stickerMaker(element, results2));
};

const asyncArtist = () => {
  debugger
  if (results2.hasChildNodes()) {
    openClose2.innerHTML = "Closed";
    removeChilds(results2);
  } else {
    openClose2.innerHTML = "Open";
    try {
      asyncAwaitCall();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}

promiseButton.addEventListener("click", fetchArtist);
asyncAwaitButton.addEventListener("click", asyncArtist);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
details {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.artist {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.artist img {
  width: 100%;
}
.artist h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.results1, .results2{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <details>
      <summary>Example</summary>
      <div class="artist">
        <img src="https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/images/pinkfloyd.jpeg">
        <h1>Pink Floyd</h1>
      </div>
    </details>
<div>
  <details open>
    <div class="first">Closed</div>
      <summary>Promise version</summary>
      <button id="promise-button">Fetch artists</button>
      <section id="promise-container"></section>
    </details>
</div>
<details open>
  <div class="second">Closed</div>
  <summary>Async/await version</summary>
  <button id="async-await-button">Fetch artists</button>
  <section id="async-await-container"></section>
</details>
    
<div>

</div>
    <div class="results1"></div>
    <div class="results2"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you understand why `fetchArtist` doesn't work, right?

Comment: In `asyncAwaitCall`, the `results.json()` returns in a promise that you should `await`. Do not use `.then((e) => artistsData.push(e))` but `const e = await results.json(); artistsData.push(e);`. Btw, `artistsData[0].forEach(…);` returns undefined, there's nothing you should `return await` there.

Comment: Also, don't use global variables `let arr = []; let artistsData = [];`. If you click the button multiple times, it would store many fetch results in that array - but you only ever display the first one. I doubt that's what you want. Omit the arrays entirely, and directly call `forEach` on the promise result.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the `asyncAwaitCall ` with

`const asyncAwaitCall = async () => {
  const results = await fetch("./api/artists.json");
  await results.json().then((e) => artistsData.push(e));
  return artistsData[0].forEach((element) => stickerMaker(element, results2));
};`

Thanks also for the tip about global variables. I understand now why my arrays were getting bigger.
Will work on a way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution thanks to Bergi who put me on track

```
const removeChilds = (parent) => {
  while (parent.lastChild) {
    parent.removeChild(parent.lastChild);
  }
};

const stickerMaker = ({ ...data }, resultDisplay) => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "artist";
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  img.src = data.image;
  h1.innerText = data.name;
  div.append(img, h1);
  resultDisplay.appendChild(div);
};

const functionFetch = () => {
  fetch("./api/artists.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) =>
      res.forEach((artist) =>
        stickerMaker({ name: artist.name, image: artist.image }, results1)
      )
    )
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
};

const fetchArtist = () => {
  if (results1.hasChildNodes()) {
    openClose1.innerText = "Closed";
    removeChilds(results1);
  } else {
    openClose1.innerText = "Open";
    functionFetch();
  }
};

const asyncAwaitCall = async () => {
  const results = await fetch("./api/artists.json");
  const e = await results.json();
  e.forEach((element) => {
    stickerMaker({ name: element.name, image: element.image }, results2);
  });
};

const asyncArtist = () => {
  if (results2.hasChildNodes()) {
    openClose2.innerText = "Closed";
    removeChilds(results2);
  } else {
    openClose2.innerText = "Open";
    try {
      asyncAwaitCall();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
};

promiseButton.addEventListener("click", fetchArtist);
asyncAwaitButton.addEventListener("click", asyncArtist);
```

Comment: Don't mix `.then()` with `await` syntax, use either one or the other. Much more straightforward :-) I've edited your answer to show this suggestion, feel free to roll back the edit if you don't like it.